# Uncaught TypeError : Cannot read property 'style' of nullsetWrap

Tags: javascript

Line with problem.

```
wrapElement.style.height = windowHeight + "px";
```

Function:

```
function setWrap() 
{
    if (document.getElementById) 
    {
        var windowHeight = getWindowHeight();
        if (windowHeight > 0) 
        {
            var wrapElement = document.getElementById("container");
            wrapElement.style.height = windowHeight + "px";
        }

    }
}
```

Comment: It seems like it doesn't find the element with the ID "container". Make sure you have a tag in your HTML with this ID.

Comment: thanks. didn't see that coming. hehehe :)

Answer (score -1, accepted):

> It seems like it doesn't find the element with the ID "container". Make sure you have a tag in your HTML with this ID. – Adrien Brunelat